# How to snooze all cloudwatch alarms at specific time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to setup snooze option for all alarms in my AWS account. To accomplish this I have tried the below terraform code. I kept my account id as dummy value 12345678.

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "snooze_alarms_rule" {
  name        = "snooze_alarms_rule"
  description = "Snooze alarms every Sunday from 12:30 PM to 6:30 PM CST"
  schedule_expression = "cron(30 18 ? * SUN *)" # 6:30 PM CST is 12:30 AM UTC, so we use that timezone
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "snooze_alarms_target" {
  rule      = aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.snooze_alarms_rule.name
  arn       = "arn:aws:automate:${var.region}:12345678:snooze:action/SetAlarmState"
  target_id = "snooze_alarms_target" #"arn:aws:sns:${var.region}:12345678:snooze"
  input = jsonencode({
    "Action": "Snooze",
    "StateValue": "ALARM",
    "Description": "Snoozing all alarms for maintenance",
    "Duration": 21600 # 6 hours in seconds
  })
}
```

But it is giving below error.

> Error: creating EventBridge Target
> (snooze_alarms_rule-snooze_alarms_target): ValidationException:
> automate is not a supported service for a target. │       status code:
> 400, request id: 56d52814-fc5f-449b-91f5-70f14a0073cf │ │   with
> aws_cloudwatch_event_target.snooze_alarms_target, │   on snooze.tf
> line 7, in resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target"
> "snooze_alarms_target": │    7: resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target"
> "snooze_alarms_target" {

I would appreciate any help offered.